# Table View with the cells having fixed height and dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, resizable, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a single tableview with multiple sections. In 1st section I want 4 tableview cells with fixed height whereas in all other sections I want tableview cells with dynamic height.
The Problem is that when I am populating the table view the dynamic cell in the section > 0
cells are not resizing according to the content.

For dynamic height, I used following lines in my viewDidLoad view controller delegate.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 83
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and the other methods are:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return configRowsInSection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    //configRowsInSection = listingsDetail.Specifications[IndexPath.sec].Configurations
    switch (section) {
       case 0:
          return 4
       default: 
        return Configurations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerCell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell
            cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
            cell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
            //addPageControl(cell.collectionView)
            
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCell
            cell.Model.text = formatTitle(listingDetail: listingsDetail) 
            cell.SerialNumber.text = "Serial# " + listingsDetail.SerialNumber
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PriceCell", for: indexPath) as! PriceCell
            cell.Price.text = "PRICE  "+listingsDetail.AskingPrice!
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HighlightCell", for: indexPath) as! HighlightCell
            cell.filterText.text = listingsDetail.filter
            cell.seatsText.text = listingsDetail.seats
            cell.wheelsText.text = listingsDetail.wheels
            cell.hoursText.text = listingsDetail.hours
        }
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecificationCell", for: indexPath) as! SpecificationCell
        cell.configValueBig.text = specificationDetail[indexPath.section-1].Configurations[indexPath.row].Desc
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var rowHeight:CGFloat!
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            rowHeight = 200
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            rowHeight = 100
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            rowHeight = 70
        }
        else {
            rowHeight = 144
        }
        return rowHeight
    }
    else {
        rowHeight = 83
        //rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension (This makes the row height as -1) 
    }
    return rowHeight
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 83
}
```

What is best way to handle a table view having one section with the rows of fixed height and other dynamic sections with the rows having variable height.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if you're getting any `NSLayoutConstraint` errors in the console.

Comment: no @PGDev none of the constraints are breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that your second section has the correct constraints from the bottom side.
The best way to handle dynamic height is to use `UITableView.automaticDimension`

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return configRowsInSection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    //configRowsInSection = listingsDetail.Specifications[IndexPath.sec].Configurations
    switch (section) {
       case 0:
          return 4
       default: 
        return Configurations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerCell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell
            cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
            cell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
            //addPageControl(cell.collectionView)
            
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCell
            cell.Model.text = formatTitle(listingDetail: listingsDetail) 
            cell.SerialNumber.text = "Serial# " + listingsDetail.SerialNumber
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PriceCell", for: indexPath) as! PriceCell
            cell.Price.text = "PRICE  "+listingsDetail.AskingPrice!
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HighlightCell", for: indexPath) as! HighlightCell
            cell.filterText.text = listingsDetail.filter
            cell.seatsText.text = listingsDetail.seats
            cell.wheelsText.text = listingsDetail.wheels
            cell.hoursText.text = listingsDetail.hours
        }
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecificationCell", for: indexPath) as! SpecificationCell
        cell.configValueBig.text = specificationDetail[indexPath.section-1].Configurations[indexPath.row].Desc
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var rowHeight:CGFloat!
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            rowHeight = 200
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            rowHeight = 100
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            rowHeight = 70
        }
        else {
            rowHeight = 144
        }
        return rowHeight
    }
   
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Constraints are being as added as required for resizable cells. None of the constraints are breaking. The problem is as soon as I put row height as UITableView.automaticDimension, all the cell in the section > 0 becomes empty and the row height returned is coming as -1

Answer (score 0):

For all the custom cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath we need to return cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerCell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell
        cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
        cell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
        //addPageControl(cell.collectionView)
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailCell
        cell.Model.text = formatTitle(listingDetail: listingsDetail) 
        cell.SerialNumber.text = "Serial# " + listingsDetail.SerialNumber
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PriceCell", for: indexPath) as! PriceCell
        cell.Price.text = "PRICE  "+listingsDetail.AskingPrice!
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HighlightCell", for: indexPath) as! HighlightCell
        cell.filterText.text = listingsDetail.filter
        cell.seatsText.text = listingsDetail.seats
        cell.wheelsText.text = listingsDetail.wheels
        cell.hoursText.text = listingsDetail.hours
        return cell
    }
}
else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecificationCell", for: indexPath) as! SpecificationCell
    cell.configValueBig.text = specificationDetail[indexPath.section-1].Configurations[indexPath.row].Desc
  return cell
}
return UITableViewCell()
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 83
```

}